# Troubles with dcolumn package - how to use underscores?

Tags: tables, dcolumn

I do have following table:

```
\documentclass[11   pt, oneside]{thesis}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} d{2.2} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} }
        \toprule
            &- \Delta G_{5.0}& $\Phi$ $J/mol$& $\nu$ & $\sigma$ & $K_{kin}$ \\
        \midrule
        Light chain & -1.74e3 & - 0.9e3 & 2.2 & 10 & 1e3 \\
        Heavy chain & - 3.24e3 &- 1.8e3 & 3.3 & 21 & 1e3 \\
        Monomer & - 9.73e3 &- 5.5e3 & 6.6 & 57 & 1e3 \\
        Dimer & - 18.0e3 &- 8.9e3 & 12.2 & 122 & 1e3 \\
        Oligomer & - 20.3e3 & - 17.1e3 & 24.2 & 378 & 1e3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What works is `G_5` but not `G_{5.0}` I do get the error:
    `Missing } inserted & \Delta G_{5.` Without the dcolumn package everything works fine.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{$G_{5.0}$}`

Comment: unrelated but `2.2` doesn't leave enough space for `- 18.0e3` also why use `d` alignment for column 2 but `p` for column 3?

Comment: you might want to look at `siunitx` and its table formatting instead. It is much more advanced than `dcolumn` (which though have its use from time to time). Regarding Davids first comment: remember this is a headline, these have to be handled specially, e.g. with `\multicolumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use `siunitx`, because it also allows for different output formats with the same input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=-2.2e1]
  S[table-format=-2.1e1]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.0e1]
}
\toprule
&{$-\Delta G_{5.0}$}& {$\Phi$ \si{J/mol}} & {$\nu$} & {$\sigma$} & {$K_{\mathrm{kin}}$} \\
\midrule
Light chain &  -1.74e3 &  -0.9e3 &  2.2 &  10 & 1e3 \\
Heavy chain &  -3.24e3 &  -1.8e3 &  3.3 &  21 & 1e3 \\
Monomer     &  -9.73e3 &  -5.5e3 &  6.6 &  57 & 1e3 \\
Dimer       & -18.0 e3 &  -8.9e3 & 12.2 & 122 & 1e3 \\
Oligomer    & -20.3 e3 & -17.1e3 & 24.2 & 378 & 1e3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\sisetup{output-exponent-marker={\,e\,},exponent-base={},exponent-product={}}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=-2.2e1]
  S[table-format=-2.1e1]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.0e1]
}
\toprule
&{$-\Delta G_{5.0}$}& {$\Phi$ \si{J/mol}} & {$\nu$} & {$\sigma$} & {$K_{\mathrm{kin}}$} \\
\midrule
Light chain &  -1.74e3 &  -0.9e3 &  2.2 &  10 & 1e3 \\
Heavy chain &  -3.24e3 &  -1.8e3 &  3.3 &  21 & 1e3 \\
Monomer     &  -9.73e3 &  -5.5e3 &  6.6 &  57 & 1e3 \\
Dimer       & -18.0 e3 &  -8.9e3 & 12.2 & 122 & 1e3 \\
Oligomer    & -20.3 e3 & -17.1e3 & 24.2 & 378 & 1e3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As you see, changing options will change the output, but the input is exactly the same.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents showing packages used.

Don't use `p` columns for numeric data, you can use `\multicolumn`
for headings which need a different format, don't use math italic for
multi-letter identifiers such as `mol`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{
l
d{3.4}
d{2.3}
d{2.1}
d{3.0}
D{e}{e}{1.1}
}

        \toprule
&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$- \Delta G_{5.0}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Phi$ $J/\mathrm{mol}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sigma$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K_{\mathrm{kin}}$}\\
        \midrule
        Light chain & -1.74e3 & - 0.9e3 & 2.2 & 10 & 1e3 \\
        Heavy chain & - 3.24e3 &- 1.8e3 & 3.3 & 21 & 1e3 \\
        Monomer & - 9.73e3 &- 5.5e3 & 6.6 & 57 & 1e3 \\
        Dimer & - 18.0e3 &- 8.9e3 & 12.2 & 122 & 1e3 \\
        Oligomer & - 20.3e3 & - 17.1e3 & 24.2 & 378 & 1e3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```